# How to host flask(python) in nginx server

Tags: python, python-requests, flask-migrate, flask-mongoengine, flask-restless

I have some html file I need to route it thorough flask(python) but how to do taht in a nginx server how can I do it

Comment: If you have time, try docker. As it makes the whole configuration part nice and easy, no overhead on fixing so many stupid Linux bugs and errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you:

https://medium.com/faun/deploy-flask-app-with-nginx-using-gunicorn-7fda4f50066a

Mark the answer correct if your problem is solved.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Follow this :

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uswgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04

and everything works fine .

Happy coding :-)